# odoo bug after restoring database

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-11

I'm using odoo `11` on localhost and recently i did database restore from
 `PgAdmin 4` and from there it completed successfully. But when i chose it from odoo login screen the screen get blank and not responds. find pic attached.

I tried this to reset javascript in the browser
`localhost:8069/web?debug=` 
but still not working.

Here are the logs:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_cron.py", line 92, in _callback
self.env['ir.actions.server'].browse(server_action_id).run()
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_actions.py", line 536, in run
res = func(action, eval_context=eval_context)
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_actions.py", line 417, in run_action_code_multi
safe_eval(action.sudo().code.strip(), eval_context, mode="exec", nocopy=True)  # nocopy allows to return 'action'
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\tools\safe_eval.py", line 370, in safe_eval
pycompat.reraise(ValueError, ValueError('%s: "%s" while evaluating\n%r' % (ustr(type(e)), ustr(e), expr)), exc_info[2])
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 85, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\tools\safe_eval.py", line 347, in safe_eval
return unsafe_eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
File "", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\ir_autovacuum.py", line 13, in power_on
return super(AutoVacuum, self).power_on(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_autovacuum.py", line 36, in power_on
self._gc_transient_models()
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir\ir_autovacuum.py", line 20, in _gc_transient_models
model._transient_vacuum(force=True)
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4048, in _transient_vacuum
self._transient_clean_rows_older_than(self._transient_max_hours * 60 * 60)
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 4009, in _transient_clean_rows_older_than
self.sudo().browse(ids).unlink()
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2857, in unlink
cr.execute(query, (sub_ids,))
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 155, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 232, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ValueError: <class 'psycopg2.IntegrityError'>: "null value in column "wizard_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, 8, null, null, 1, 2018-01-01 03:32:24.944104, 1, 2018-01-01 03:32:25.077112).
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE ONLY "public"."change_password_user" SET "wizard_id" = NULL WHERE $1 OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) "wizard_id""
" while evaluating
'model.power_on()'
```

[image: odoo screen]

Answer (score 2):

I think some method is not found and your odoo source code is old so get the latest code form odoo github: https://github.com/odoo/odoo

and then after in terminal throw update the all module like:

./odoo-bin -d your_database_name --db-filter your_database_name --addons-path your_all_addons_path_name **-u all**

this is helpfull tip

Answer (score 0):

may be you have some missing files, try to restore also a folder named: **filestore** 
that folder can be found in: 
/home/$User/.local/share/Odoo/filestore 
replace **$User** with your ubuntu username